# How to test equality between http Request objects

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-test

I want to test equality between these two request objects but I can not figure out how to implement the `hash` and `equality` operator on a third-party package for example `http` package.
How can I use `equatable` package on the Response object of `http` package?

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
test('equality test', () async {
        final uri = baseUri.replace(path: 'account/login');
        final request = http.Request(RequestMethod.post, uri);
        final request2 = http.Request(RequestMethod.post, uri);
        expect(request, equals(request2));
});
```

The output is

```
Expected: Request:<POST https://test.webapi.odinpool.com:1989/account/login>
  Actual: Request:<POST https://test.webapi.odinpool.com:1989/account/login>
```

Which it doesn't complete successfully.
I want to test the remote server API to call the correct API endpoint when creating the request object and test the method with `verify.called(1)` method but it seems the test package can not test equality between `http.Request` objects.

Comment: You could create your own class that extends http.Request and implements == operation that would check for the relevant properties from the Request you want to compare.

Comment: Or, better, create an extension that implements `compare` (or your choice of name). If you do override `==` you should then override `hash` too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Richard Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9597706/richard-heap) comment I came up with a solution:

```dart
class RequestX extends http.Request with EquatableMixin{
  RequestX(super.method, super.url);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [super.headers, super.method, super.url, super.body];

}
```

This `RequestX` class compared two objects successfully.